# How to understand this film name 'Tron: Legacy'?

Tags: meaning

I have checked a dictionary, 'tron' isn't a word in English. And someone translated into my native language:

> Creat: fight record

Comment: Do you mean Croat ?

Comment: The meaning of "legacy" here is "anything handed down from the past, as from an ancestor or predecessor: *the legacy of ancient Rome.*" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/legacy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tron is the name of an older movie, and "Tron: Legacy" is a sequel.

While "Tron" is just a made-up name for the movie (it should just be transliterated into another language).

"Legacy" exists to show that in the sequel they're continuing the history of the old story.

Comment: "Tron" is a made up word but it doesn't HAVE to be transliterated: it's made up of "elecTRONic" and thus translations might be better-served by coining a similar word in that language. (Though since the original is so old, the new movie should just re-use whatever the old title was (if it exists))

Comment: I agree with Mr. Shiny and New: Movie titles don't need to transliterated; I am used to movie titles used in Italy that are completely different from the American one. In most of the cases, the used title is something that has the same meaning of the original one; to keep the original meaning doesn't mean to literally translate the English title.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084827/trivia

> TRON is also a debugging command in
>   the BASIC programming language,
>   meaning "TRace ON." However, Steven
>   Lisberger, has stated in interviews
>   that he took the name from the word
>   "electronic," and did not know about
>   the BASIC command until later

Comment: To be fair to Lisberger, "TRace ON" appears in one dialect of BASIC, not the base language itself.

Comment: Interesting! I knew about the TRON command  and always assumed it had the programming meaning since TRON is trying to stop the Master Control program and the TRON command is used to debug programs and figure out what they are doing. Seems I read too much into it!

Answer (score -1):

Actually if you look up tron in Norway, it is an actual name, it's a family name dating back to the late 1700's. The Norwegian translation means "growing".

Comment: Do you have sources?

Comment: _Tron_ is not a family name, but a given name. It is a variant of the male name [Trond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trond_(name)), and it is indeed most likely derived from _þróandi_ ‘growing, prospering’ in Old Norse. I doubt this had any influence on the naming of the movie, though.